# How to delete attach function of code in R

Tags: r

How do I generate the graph without using the `attach` function? Some people said that it's not good to use the `attach`, but I don't know how to solve it.

Executable code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

#dataset df1
df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Monday"),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

#Generate graph

dmda<-"2021-07-01"

datas<-df1 %>%
  filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(name = as.numeric(name))
colnames(datas)<-c("Days","Numbers")
attach(datas)
plot(Numbers ~ Days, ylim=c(0,20))

model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 47,b2 = 0))

new.data <- data.frame(Days = seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45))
lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `plot`/`nls`, there is a `data` option which can be used instead of `attach`ing.  It can go out of proportion when there are 1000s of columns i.e. it creates 1000 objects in the global env

```
plot(Numbers ~ Days, ylim=c(0,20), data = datas)
model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 47,b2 = 0), data = datas)
new.data <- data.frame(Days = with(datas, seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45)))
lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data))
```

-output

[image]

If we want to extract column values, there are options like `$` or `[[` and if we have to do this multiple times, use `with`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways, here some:

#### Use the columns from the data.frame as vectors with operator $

```
plot(x = datas$Days,y = datas$Numbers, ylim=c(0,20))
```

[image]

#### An interesting alternative, is to use ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(datas,aes(x = Days,y = Numbers))+
  geom_point(shape = 21,size = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Did not see I was writing while you already answered, if it makes you unconfortable I will delete the second option